# S-Matrix and normalization of states

Tags: quantum-field-theory, s-matrix-theory, normalization

I'm trying to understand what is the [S-matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-matrix) in QFT. People say that it has to be a unitary matrix, but that I guess will change with a different normalization of the incoming and outgoing states. My question is, how do we choose the normalization of states when discussing the S-matrix? And why in general a state of two identical particles has a normalization with an additional factor of $1/\sqrt{2}$ in comparison to states with non-identical particles?

Comment: Whether an operator is unitary or not has nothing to do with the normalization of your basis states. Unitarity means $U^\dagger U = 1$. So if you chose to normalize your states to 2, or something completely stupid like $1+a^2 k_x^2$ (where $a$ is just some length for dimensional reasons), instead of 1 then the unitary operators would preserve this stupid normalization. What changes when you change normalization are the Born rule and resolution of the identity $1=\sum |n\rangle\langle n|$ (since you have to divide by a normalizing factor to compensate).

Comment: Unitarity ensures that "probability is conserved" i.e. the probability interpretation a la Born's rule continues to make sense. Changing normalization of states is not a problem, since physical answers always look like $\dfrac{\langle s|U^\dagger U|s\rangle}{\langle s|s\rangle}$

Answer (score 1):

$$S_{\alpha \beta} = \langle\beta^+|\alpha^- \rangle$$

The normalization of states don't have any relation to the S Matrix. The interpretation of S-matrix in terms of Rates and Cross-sections may be have some implicit relation to the normalization of the In- and Out- States. If we set a box with very big volume, than we can normalize the In- and Out- states. By this procedure we can see that the normalization don't affect explicit the equations of Rates and Cross-Sections. Only thing that matters for S matrix is the orthogonality of the set of In- and Out- States.

We can generalize the S marix, and seen as a operator in tha basis of free states. Than, we can (or not) normalize this basis. But again, this don't affect the Rates and Cross-Sections.